# Meaning of %<>% operation

Tags: r, dplyr

What does this operation do?

```
test  %<>% select(name_list)
```

Comment: Sorry for the tags, I did not find the correct ones

Comment: Did you read `?\`%<>%\``  and look at the examples given?

Comment: the above operation you use is just to select only column `name_list` from your dataframe called `test`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is from a package called `magrittr`.

`%<>%` means: Take the left part, modify it with the right part and overwrite the left variable.

if you are more familiar with `dplyr`, it ist the equivalent of:

```r
test <- test %>% select(name_list)
```

the `%>%` is a so called *pipe operator*. It pipes its left side as input into the right side.  a normal base R input would look like this:

```r
test <- select(test,name_list)
```

This gets tedious when chaining series of operations on the data. This is what the pipe operator is for.

`select` means to only return certain columns of a table. In this case `name_list` is the name of the column.